# Why does Visual Studio mark my CPP and Header files as Miscellaneous Files, leading them to not be affected by intelli sense

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

#### The problem

You probably already read the long title: My VS 2019 keeps flagging my header and CPP files as "Miscellaneous Files", leading them to be not affected by intelli sense. I have this problem for quite a while now, so I'd really appreciate help. I should maybe add that I am using CMake, which could, indeed, be the root of the issue. So, for this sake, I'm only providing the CMake files, you probably can write the wrong code and check for yourself (:
This is the root CMake file:

```
# CMakeList.txt: CMake-Projektdatei der obersten Ebene. Führen Sie hier die globale Konfiguration aus,
# und schließen Sie Unterprojekte ein.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project ("FirstCPPEngine")

# Schließen Sie Unterprojekte ein.
add_subdirectory ("FirstCPPEngine")
```

And this is the CMake file in FirstCPPEngine:

```
# CMakeList.txt: CMake-Projekt für "FirstCPPEngine". Schließen Sie die Quelle ein, und definieren Sie
# projektspezifische Logik hier.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

# Fügen Sie der ausführbaren Datei dieses Projekts eine Quelle hinzu.
# "src/ResourceManagement/ResourceLocation.h" "src/ResourceManagement/ResourceLocation.cpp" 
add_executable (FirstCPPEngine "src/Main.cpp" "src/subfolder/insertyourwrongcodehere.h" "src/subfolder/insertyourwrongcodehere.cpp" )


target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
```

If there are any files that I forgot, please tell me so in the comments. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Often C++ will give up after a the first few errors on a subject rather than highlight the entire source in red.  We do not know if this is what you are seeing without a [mcve].

Comment: I can assure you that the problem is more likely in your code than in CMake or VS.

Comment: If you could provide a minimal example or code snippet, it will help solve the problem. Of course, IntelliSense sometimes has problems, which needs to be analyzed according to the actual situation. You could refer to Microsoft Docs about [Configure a C++ project for IntelliSense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-cpp-intellisense-configuration?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Alrigth, I've now provided the full project, as I am currently using it on my disk.

Comment: "a complete copy" is not minimal.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Yeah, you are kinda right, but the project isn't that big (I could seem that it is big because there are some libs like GLFW and GLAD in the libs folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ traditional (non-modules) compiler compiles `.cpp` files into `.o` files, then the linker takes `.o` files and links them into a binary.  The exact extension of these files is not fixed (you can convince a compiler to consume `.foo` source files and produce `.bob` object files).

You may note that `.h` files are not mentioned here.

Header files are consumed by the C/C++ preprocessor when compiling a source file.  They are textually included -- their contents are literally copued and pasted into the compiler's version of thr source file when the `#include` occurs.

A header file that isn't included is a text file.  What more, it may not be valid to compile that test file seperately from a cpp file at all.

In other languages that don't use the textual include model, their interface declaration files can be and are compiled "stand alone".  In C++ a compiler doing that is making up something that doesn't really happen.

A decent thing to do is to make stub cpp files that do nothing but include each of your header files.  This ensures each of your header files in turn includes its dependencies, and should fix your intellisense problem.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: @budsc probably, but nit for free.  I mean you could write a python script that auto writes those and adds them to your project.

Comment: That honestly sounds terrible... Why doesn't VS2019 have this feature out of the box? And always running a python script after adding a file... Honestly, this doesn't sound that great(and efficient), I wonder why this is used in the industry.

Comment: @Budschie Because header files that aren't included are really strange things as far as a CPP project is concerned.  You'd expect at least a test suite.

Comment: @Budschie Also, sloppy C++ programmers often have `.h` files that **don't** work when you make a cpp file that just `#include`s them.  So you'll get a spam of red squiggles.   Their `.cpp` files, meanwhile, are almost always intended to actually compile as-is, with project instructions for what build flags, which can be mined.  Red squiggles from failing to be able to compile it is reasonable.  Note that C++'s incoming modules feature will make the header-file equivalent independently compiled, which will permit independent syntax checking.